# bootstrap-table design not working

Tags: bootstrap-table

I'm trying to create a website with a table on it.. I search for templates and found the bootstrap-table design... the example is working perfectly fine but if I want to use this bootstrap-table-javascript on my own table its not working.

Here is my jsp code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- Scriptimporte: -->
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Tabellenpflege mit XML-Datei -->
        <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
        <%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
        <c:import var="bookInfo" url="tables/xml_doc.xml"/>
        <x:parse xml="${bookInfo}" var="output"/>

        <!-- css-Dateien -->
        ...


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="start_header">

            <div id="start_logo"><img src="icons/logo.jpg" alt="" /></div>


        </div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main">           
        <div class="row">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked home"><use xlink:href="#stroked-home"></use></svg></a></li>
                <li class="active">Icons</li>
            </ol>
        </div><!--/.row-->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Tables</h1>
            </div>
                </div><!--/.row-->
                <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Testlist</h2></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table data-toggle="table"  data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">

                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
                                                        <th data-field="name"  data-sortable="true">Name</th>
                                <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Durchwahl</th>
                                                        <th data-field="present" data-sortable="true">Anwesend</th>
                            </tr>
                                                    </thead>

                                                    <tbody>


                                                        <x:forEach var="test" select="$output/books/book">
                                                            <tr>

                                                                <td>
                                                                   1
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <x:out select="name" />
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <x:out select="nr" />
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    ja
                                                                </td>    
                                                            </tr>   
                                                        </x:forEach>
                                                    </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div><!--/.row-->  
        </div><!--/.main-->

    </body>
</html>
```

I thought the bootstrap-table.js-function applys all his methods on all tables in the document which have the data-toggle="table".

Comment: Du brauchst nur einen Bootstrap script import, wenn Du die actuelle Version von Bootstrap benuetzt. Zweitens Bootstrap import kommt nach dem jQuery import.
You need only one Bootstrap import if you are using the latest Bootstrap. Secondly, your Bootstrap reference must follow the jQuery reference. :)
Lastly use the Bootstrap table class in the table tag: class="table".

Comment: nice that was fast man :D thx dude its working!

Comment: And you need a reference to the Bootstrap.css file.

Comment: @user0815123 - if solved, please accept answer and/or update the question to include the solution (use markdown to add bold or header wrap, and "---" for <hr>, to help readability. I also prefer to update titles to include "solved" as well, but not so needed on SO)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need only one Bootstrap import if you are using the latest Bootstrap. Secondly, your Bootstrap reference must follow the jQuery reference. :) Lastly use the Bootstrap table class in the table tag: class="table". And you need a reference to the Bootstrap.css file.